# Capistrano is failing because it cannot connect to remote git repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, capistrano

I am trying to deploy using Capistrano 3.x.

I configured agent forwarding in my *~/.ssh/config* file:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
  Hostname xxxx
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile /path/to/codecommit_rsa
```

I did the same thing for my server connection with `ForwardAgent yes` also.

I verified my server allows agent forwarding in the */etc/ssh/sshd_config* file also:

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

```
  INFO ----------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO START 2017-11-18 16:09:44 -0500 cap production deploy
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO [b43ed70f] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp as deploy@50.116.2.15
 DEBUG [b43ed70f] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp
  INFO [b43ed70f] Finished in 1.132 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-testapp-production-blankman.sh 0.0%
  INFO Uploading /tmp/git-ssh-testapp-production-blankman.sh 100.0%
  INFO [b1a90dc1] Running /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-testapp-production-blankman.sh as deploy@50.116.2.15
 DEBUG [b1a90dc1] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod 700 /tmp/git-ssh-testapp-production-blankman.sh
  INFO [b1a90dc1] Finished in 0.265 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [b323707d] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/fuweb HEAD as deploy@50.116.2.15
 DEBUG [b323707d] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/git-ssh-testapp-production-blankman.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote ssh://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/fuweb HEAD )
 DEBUG [b323707d]   Permission denied (publickey).
 DEBUG [b323707d]   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: it looks like the deploy process successfully connected to your server, but fails to authenticate with CodeCommit. Did you already [add your *public* key to the IAM user](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-without-cli.html#setting-up-without-cli-add-key) for CodeCommit?

Comment: @CyRossignol Yes on my laptop I can connect to code commit just fine.

Comment: Did you start an SSH agent process on both the local and remote server, and `ssh-add` the key on the local box? Don't mean to bore you with these basics, but I can't assume these prereqs just by looking at the question :)

Comment: @CyRossignol Yes I did ssh-add.  How do I start it on the remote server and how do I check if it is running?   Actually it must be running because I can 'ssh deploy@1.1.1.1 and I get into the remote server just fine.

Comment: The agent (`ssh-agent`) is different from the SSH server (`sshd`). The server accepts connections, while the (optional) agent manages credentials. After logging into the server, we can run `env | grep SSH` to determine if the agent is running. Look for variables like `SSH_AGENT_PID` or `SSH_AGENT_SOCK`. Some systems start an agent automatically on login. If it isn't started, we can use `eval "$(ssh-agent)"` to start the agent on the server.

Comment: @CyRossignol this looks to be the issue, it still fails but that is because I have to figure out how to start ssh-agent on login b/c capistrano will create a new ssh login session and it won't be turned on for that session.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, an SSH agent must run on the *remote* server as well as on the local machine that contains the key because the agents at each end need to cooperate to forward the key information. The agent (`ssh-agent`) is different from the SSH server (`sshd`). The server accepts connections, while the (otherwise optional) agent manages credentials.

Some systems start an agent automatically upon login. To check if this is the case, log in to the server and run:

```
$ env | grep SSH
```

...looking for variables like `SSH_AGENT_PID` or `SSH_AGENT_SOCK`.  If it isn't started, we can execute the following command to start the agent on the server:

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

As we can see, this *evaluates* the output of the `ssh-agent` command because `ssh-agent` returns a script that sets some needed environment variables in the session.

We'll need to make sure the agent starts automatically upon login so that it doesn't interfere with the deploy process. If we checked and determined that the agent does *not*, in fact, start on login, we can add the last command to the "deploy" user's *~/.profile* file (or *~/.bash_profile*).

Note also that the host specified in the local *~/.ssh/config* must match the name or IP address of the host that we want to *forward credentials to*, not the host that ultimately authenticates using the forwarded key. We need to change:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
```

...to:

```
Host 50.116.2.15
```

We can verify that the SSH client performs agent forwarding by checking the verbose output:

```
$ ssh -v deploy@50.116.2.15
...
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
...
```

Of course, be sure to register any needed keys with the local agent by using `ssh-add` (this can also be done automatically when logging in as shown above). We can check which keys the agent loaded at any time with:

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make Capistrano aware that you expect it to forward your local key. This can be done by going into you project's `config/deploy.rb` and adding this line:

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

IIRC, Capistrano executes commands remotely through [SSHKit](https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit), so even if you invoke the `ssh-agent` and add a key locally, I can't say if it will persist for the next command.

Comment: `ssh-agent` backgrounds to store keys in memory. SSHKit uses [Net::SSH](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) which [attempts to connect to a running agent](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/078dcbdfd42bd7304db90fd3007c11b8249190d5/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb#L76) by [default](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/978da67c7b49e8a8dc26808ad2608527abacb095/lib/net/ssh.rb#L181). Net::SSH [will parse OpenSSH config files](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/198ccf5d2707eb85e6b2d0aac9a14eb2c0855be8/lib/net/ssh/config.rb) to determine if it needs to perform agent forwarding.

Comment: We can set `:use_agent` and `:forward_agent` to override the SSH configuration from the environment if needed.

Answer (score 1):

This usually helps me:

```
ssh-add -D   
ssh-agent    
ssh-add
```